# how to get display: none to work for div inside a form

Tags: javascript, html, css

UPDATE: So it seems that display:none is not working at all, when visibility:hidden is removed from the .hide class the divs show up, so it's an issue with display:none not working here.

UPDATE#2: OK so basically all the divs also have a .panel class which handles all the styling and has a display flex on it which is overriding the display:none from the .hide class. The issue now is how to give the .hide class higher priority without using !important.

```
     _____________________________________
```

In my html I have a form with a few divs inside it and each div has a button which when clicked adds a .hide class to the div and removes the .hide class from the next div, until we get to the last div and then the form is submitted with all the data.

So the HTML is basically like this:

```
<form> 
  <div class='panel' id='div1'></div>
  <div class='hide panel' id='div2'></div>
  <div class='hide panel' id='div3'></div>
  <div class='hide panel' id='div4'></div>
</form>
```

And the .hide class is:

```
.hide {
   display:none;
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

The issue I am having is that even though the divs show and dissapear properly they still seem to be on the page so that you have to scroll down a lot of empty screen space to get to the footer.

I am assuming this has something to do with the fact that the divs are inside a form and even though the div's are being set to display:none the form is still there so they arent going away.

How do I get this to work???

Thanks

Comment: `visibility: hidden;` is redundant when using `display: none;` --- The current code will hide the divs inside the form.

Comment: any additional js or css you could add? so we can reproduce the problem

Comment: actually the display:none isnt working at all, if I take out the visibility:hidden the divs are showing

Comment: you should use the hidden property, it's easier

Comment: well then I have the problem I made this question about its hidden but its taking space on the page so the footer is way down at the bottom

Comment: does your form has a fixed height ?

Comment: nope no css on the form only on the divs, divs dont have height either only min and max widths

Comment: when i adapt my example with your class instead of the `hidden` property, it work well

Comment: What does it show in the dev tools? Does `.hide` show up with `display: none` set?

Comment: You might have something in your full code giving you an error. Could you insert a codepen or jsfiddle into your post?

Comment: @Rob Moll, good call, its actually geting overwritten by the other class on them that handles all the styling and has display:flex, need to figure out how to give the hide class priority

Comment: Make your rule more specific. [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: You can use the `hidden` property I think it's the best thing to do in your case plus it is well suported

Comment: @Namysh thank you but I would rather get the display:none working.

Comment: @Rob Moll working on it

Comment: Try `div.hide.panel {display: none};`

Comment: @Rob Moll that works even with just div.hide ! Thanks, post an answer so I can accept it. Also do you know how come my JS script is still able to add and remove the class as .hide even though its now div.hide???

Comment: `div.hide` is simply saying "any div with a class of 'hide', while `.hide` says "any element with a class of 'hide'" so both reach the destination of your class (.hide). I'll write an answer.

Comment: I do get that from the css side but from the JS side if I tell classlist.add('.hide') how does it know that div.hide is a match? Does it check somehow what type the object that is calling it is and then check for the .hide for that object? Seems to be because I also had a button using the .hide and I just had to write button.hide class to get that to work as well. So the JS wasn't applying the div.hide to the button but now does apply the button.hide to it. Just wondering how it knows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turns out to be a case of a CSS declaration being over-ridden by another CSS declaration which is more specific.

As in this example, a second class, `.panel` was applying `display: flex` to the div's. The user created a CSS class `.hide` which applied `display: none`. For reasons not made apparent here, the `.panel` declaration was more specific than the `.hide` declaration and as a result `.hide` was over-ridden.

Maybe a result of **CASCADE**:

> Stylesheets cascade — at a very simple level, this means that the
> order of CSS rules matter; when two rules apply that have equal
> specificity the one that comes last in the CSS is the one that will be
> used.

And/or **SPECIFICITY**:

> Specificity is how the browser decides which rule applies if multiple
> rules have different selectors, but could still apply to the same
> element. It is basically a measure of how specific a selector's
> selection will be.

And finally **INHERITANCE**:

> Some CSS property values set on parent elements are inherited by their
> child elements, and some aren't.
>
> For example, if you set a color and font-family on an element, every
> element inside it will also be styled with that color and font, unless
> you've applied different color and font values directly to them.

Ultimately the issue was discovered by observing the dev tools in the browser. The user could see that the `.hide` `display:none` declaration was lined-through indicating it was over-ridden.

The solution then becomes making the `.hide` CSS declaration more specific than `.panel`.

This was accomplished by changing the CSS declaration to:

```
div.hide {
   display:none;
}
```

MDN has a great explanation of the concept of [cascade, specificity, and inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance#specificity_2)

> At some point, you will be working on a project and you will find that the CSS you thought should be applied to an element is not working. Usually, the problem is that you have created two rules which could potentially apply to the same element. The cascade, and the closely-related concept of specificity, are mechanisms that control which rule applies when there is such a conflict. Which rule is styling your element may not be the one you expect, so you need to understand how these mechanisms work.

Answer (score 1):

With `visibility: hidden`, the element is not visible but still occupy the space of the web page.
With `display: none`, the element is not visible and collapse entire.

So use `display: none` only to collapse the element.
Don't use both.

Update: This works as can be seen here: https://jsbin.com/pegezij/edit?html,css,output

Comment: actually the display:none isnt working at all, if I take out the visibility:hidden the divs are showing

Comment: @Jack I created a POC and it seems to be working fine.
https://jsbin.com/pegezij/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

You just can use the `hidden` property like this :

```js
const div = [...document.querySelectorAll('div')];

const firstDiv = div.shift();

firstDiv.onclick = function action(event){
  this.hidden = true;
  
  const nextDiv = div.shift();
  
  if(nextDiv) {
    nextDiv.hidden = false;
    nextDiv.onclick = action;
    event.preventDefault();
  } else {
    // no preventDefault here for submitting the form
  }
}
```

```css
form {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<form> 
  <div id='div1'>1: <button>Hide</button></div>
  <div id='div2' hidden >2: <button>Hide</button></div>
  <div id='div3' hidden >3: <button>Hide</button></div>
  <div id='div4' hidden >4: <button>Hide</button></div>
</form>
```

As you can see the form's height stay the same. You can use indexes instead of shifting the array.

[More reading here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/hidden)

Answer (score 0):

as long as you have two classes so you need to toggle between class like this

```js
function toggle() {
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.show');
for (var i = 0; i<divs.length; i++) {
divs[i].classList.toggle('hide');
}
}
```

```css
.show {
display:block;
}
.hide {
display:none;
}
form {
border: 4px solid black;
}
```

```html
<form> 
<div id='div1'>test</div>
<div class='show' id='div2'>1</div>
<div class='show' id='div3'>2</div>
<div class='show' id='div4'>3</div>
</form>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="toggle" onClick="toggle()" />
```